# Trigger IsSelected = true on IsVisibleChanged without local styles and code behind (example TabItem)

Tags: wpf, triggers

What is the best way, if there is any, without code behind, to trigger in one TabItem (and change its IsSelected = true) when another's TabItem in the same TabControl has its visibility changed? IsVisibleChanged is not a RoutedEvent. And my controls are all styled from resources so I have to avoid by all means setting local styles (to be able to use Datatriggers).

Currently I can only think of doing this in code behind:

```
        private void TabItem1_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem2.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Will the selected TabItem always be the same (e.g. a default TabItem) when the other TabItem goes to Collapsed? If not - what behaviour do you need?

Comment: Depending on two states in the application, I make changes in the tabs and want select the first tab as default any time the state changes

Answer (score 1):

> And my controls are all styled from resources so I have to avoid by all means setting local styles

Not a good reason (at least when those resources do not change at runtime) you can just use [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx), e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

Other than that you could use additional tools like Interactivity from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22829) which allows triggering both independent of styles and on all events.